# how to optimize theta using octave fminunc function

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, octave, linear-regression

*I'm trying to optimize theta over a linear regression problem where the training set X has 3-column including bias and using fminunc function to optimize theta. But error is showing during calling this function.
My training data X has 47x3 size and y has 47x1. I wrote cost function that will be called from  fminunc function.

code for cost function for this linear regression problem:

```
function [J,grad] = computeCost(theta,X,y)  
J = 0;
theta=[0;0;0];
m=length(y);
J=(1/(2))*sum((((X*theta)-y)).^2);
grad=sum(((X*theta)-y)'*X);
end
```

code for using fminunc :

```
v=load('ex1data2.txt');
X=v(:,1:2);
y=v(:,3);
X=[ones(size(y)),X];
theta=[0;0;0];
options=optimset('GradObj','on','MaxIter','100');
[a,b]=fminunc(@(t)(computeCost(t,X,y)),theta,options);
```

When running this above code octave IDE showing error message :
    error: **doglegm**: operator : nonconformant arguments (op1 is 3x3, op2 
    is 1x1)
    error: called from
    fminunc>**doglegm** at line 458 column 5
    fminunc at line 266 column 9*